# react-native-push-notification onRegister fires correctly, but onNotification never catched

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

On Android I have no problems, on iOS I am able to catch `onRegister` event and get the token correctly, but when I test push notifications, the event `onNotification` seems not working: it never fires.

My configure code is:

```
const configure = async () => {
    console.log('push notification configured');
    PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('registrationError', (e) => { alert(JSON.stringify(e)) });

    PushNotification.configure({

        onRegister: function (token) {
            //process token
            alert('Token! ' + JSON.stringify(token));
            console.log('[CATCHED] onRegister:', token);
            db.setToken(token).catch(
                console.log('[ERROR] device push token has not been saved on the database'),
            );
        },

        onNotification: async function (notification) {
            console.log('[CATCHED] onNotification: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
            let notifType = '';
            //console.log('notification received: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
            if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                notifType = getNotificationType(
                    JSON.parse(notification.data.data).type,
                );
            } else {
                notifType = getNotificationType(
                    notification.type,
                );
            }
            //console.log('notification type: >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ' + notifType);
            //console.log('notification s: ------------------> ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
            switch (notifType) {
                {...}
            }
            // process the notification
            // required on iOS only
            if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
            }

        },
        senderID: '-----',

        permissions: {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true,
        },

        popInitialNotification: true,
        requestPermissions: true,
    });
};
```

In iOS, the console log `[CATCHED] onRegister:` fires correctly, but `[CATCHED] onNotification:` is never fired.

Comment: Try setting `notification.iosDisplayInForeground`in your app.json or set `_displayInForeground` to true in your push message.

Comment: Hey :) Please provide your AppDelegate file to see how you configured your project

Comment: Hi @kitsune Did you obtain the notification permission in your iOS app

Comment: No, I didn't see the alert that asks for notification permissions.Sometimes it works, sometimes not.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have exactly the same issue

Comment: About iOS, I solved relinking all manually following carefully the linking guide on GitHub repo's page, CMD+K in Xcode to clean the project, removed Pods, update the react-native-push-notifications plugin to the latest version and reinstalling pods (critical part is in the AppDelegate.m), restart metro from scratch and clear watchman. This is a nuclear option, but may works for you.